# Mongodb: Selecting embedded document in a collection

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I have a collection like below. Embedded style. The problem is the query won't select the intended `user` with the given `ID`. What am I doing wrong? Any other better way?

**Note:** If I remove `user` bit from the query, it returns all the records with the intended `statuses` so the query is fine itself.

Thanks in advance

```
    $query = $dm
        ->createQueryBuilder('EmMaBundle:Design')
        ->field('user.id')->equals('53d62b692ac1fb22d9000000')
        ->field('status')->equals(0);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should query `user.$id`

2) The `user.$id` field contains an `ObjectId` instead of a `String`. Try it with a `MongoId` e.g.

```
$userId = new \MongoId("53d62b692ac1fb22d9000000");

$query = $dm
    ->createQueryBuilder('EmMaBundle:Design')
    ->field('user.$id')->equals($userId)
    ->field('status')->equals(0);
```

---

shell query:

```
db.collection.find( { 'user.$id': ObjectId("53d62b692ac1fb22d9000000") } )
```

Comment: I tried `'user.id'`, `'user._id'`, `'user.$id'` and `new \MongoId("53d62b692ac1fb22d9000000")` versions but none worked.

Comment: Does the mongo shell query I just added to my answer return any results for you?

Comment: Shell query didn't work as well. Apparently querying embedded docs is a painful process anyway so I decided to persist `user.id` directly into the doc as `userId` field as well now so that I can just query it instead. This solves the problem for now. I've read up on `$elemMatch` too.

Comment: Mm, odd! I'm sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: I just wiped the db and tried again. Now it works. I don't understand why. I had some more strange issues before so I think I should maybe start looking into different NoSQLs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $dm
        ->createQueryBuilder('EmMaBundle:Design')
        ->field('user._id')->equals('53d62b692ac1fb22d9000000')
        ->field('status')->equals(0);
```

Hey there,
try to use user._id instead of user.id in your selector.